# Generating an RPM to also run "make" and "make install"

Tags: redis, centos, rpm

I want to install redis by creating a rpm. I want to run all the commands that need to happen:

```
tar xvzf redis-3.2.1.tar.gz
cd redis-3.2.1/
make
make test
make install
```

Is there any documentation on creating a `.spec` file to do this?

Comment: you can look here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/02/rpm-build-package-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can write a *.spec file from scratch, it is usually easier to modify an existing *.rpm. E.g. you can often easily upgrade to redis-3.2.1 from the existing resist-3.0.6 package here: http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/Packages/r/redis-3.0.6-3.fc24.src.rpm

Comment: In a nutshell: Download and rebuild the older 3.0.6 SRPM by doing "rpmbuild  -bb redis*.src.rpm". Then install with "rpm -Uvh *.src.rpm." Edit the redis.spec and change the Version, as well as the tarball used to build (which you need to download and add so that rpm build can find). Then try a new build with "rpm build -ba redid.spec"